# scala splitting strings from a Stream[String] => GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: scala, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I don't understand why spliting a `Stream[String]` produces a `GC overhead limit exceeded` depending on whether `str` in `Stream[String].flatMap{string => str.split(" ")}` is invariant or randomly emitted.

When `str` is invariant, no overhead happens instead it will in the random case.

I am not referencing objects in the looping blocks.

I use `def` to declare `Stream`s in order to produce non-accumulating `Stream`s.

Thanks for insights.

Here's my code:

```
import scala.util.Random

object DataOps{
  val randomGen:Random = new Random()
  def randomText:String = (0 to 300).map(x => randomGen.nextString(10)).mkString(" ")
  val text:String = Array.fill(300)(randomGen.nextString(10)).mkString(" ")

  //return a stream of strind using the same 'txt:String'
  def infiniteInvariantDataStream(cnt:Int): Stream[String] = { 
    if (cnt>0) text#::infiniteInvariantDataStream(cnt-1)
    else Stream[String]()
  }

  //return a Stream of random string
  def infiniteDataStream(cnt:Int):Stream[String] = { 
    if (cnt>0) randomText#::infiniteDataStream(cnt-1)
    else Stream[String]()
  }
}

object BasicOps{
  def dummyStringStreamSplit(datastream: Stream[String]) = { 
      datastream
        .flatMap(txt => txt.split(" ")) 
        .foreach(word => word)
  }
}

object scalaOverflow extends App{

  val n_lines:Int = 1000000

  println("splitting looping over invariant text")
  def datastream1:Stream[String] = DataOps.infiniteInvariantDataStream(n_lines)
  BasicOps.dummyStringStreamSplit(datastream1)
  println("INVARIANT LINE SPLIT OK: no heap overflow")

  println("splitting looping over random text")
  def datastream3:Stream[String] = DataOps.infiniteDataStream(n_lines)
  BasicOps.dummyStringStreamSplit(datastream3)
  println("RANDOM LINE SPLIT OK: no heap overflow")

}
```

and here 's the error :

```
splitting looping over invariant text
INVARIANT LINE SPLIT OK: no heap overflow
splitting looping over random text
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2840)
        at java.lang.Character.toString(Character.java:2136)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
        at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:198)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$addString$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.addString(TraversableOnce.scala:343)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.addString(Traversable.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:309)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.mkString(Traversable.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:311)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.mkString(Traversable.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.mkString(Traversable.scala:104)
        at scala.util.Random.nextString(Random.scala:89)
        at DataOps$$anonfun$randomText$1.apply(scalaOverflow.scala:5)
        at DataOps$$anonfun$randomText$1.apply(scalaOverflow.scala:5)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at DataOps$.randomText(scalaOverflow.scala:5)
        at DataOps$.infiniteDataStream(scalaOverflow.scala:16)
        at DataOps$$anonfun$infiniteDataStream$1.apply(scalaOverflow.scala:16)
        at DataOps$$anonfun$infiniteDataStream$1.apply(scalaOverflow.scala:16)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1117)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1107)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Stream.scala:458)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Stream.scala:458)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.append(Stream.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Stream.scala:241)
```

**UPDATE**

Actually, the reason of this streaming is rooted in the method below. The whole point being to turn a java `while` loop into a functional friendly `Stream`:

```
import java.sql.{Connection, ResultSet, Statement, DriverManager}
def sqlStream(psqlResult: ResultSet, colname:String): Stream[(Int,String)] = {
    val state:Boolean = psqlResult.next()
    if (state && psqlResult.getString(colname) != null)
        (psqlResult.getRow(), psqlResult.getString(colname))#::sqlStream(psqlResult, colname)
    else if (state)
        sqlStream(psqlResult, colname)
    else
        Stream[(Int,String)]()
}
```

Should I have considered a better alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `datastream` in `dummyStringStreamSplit` effectively acts like a `val` and maintains a reference to the beginning of the passed-in stream. This is what causes the unbounded memory use and the eventual GC overhead limit exceeded error.

There is really no way to make a method that takes a `Stream` and computes something based on every element (rather than just returning a new `Stream`) safe. At the very least, there is no way to guarantee that client code didn't pass you a `Stream` being held in a variable somewhere.

If you instead define `dummyStringStreamSplit` like:

```
def dummyStringStreamSplit(datastream: Stream[String]) =
  datastream.flatMap(txt => txt.split(" "))
```

You can then do:

```
println("splitting looping over random text")
def datastream3:Stream[String] = DataOps.infiniteDataStream(n_lines)
def datastream3Split = BasicOps.dummyStringStreamSplit(datastream3)
datastream3Split.foreach(word => word)
println("RANDOM LINE SPLIT OK: no heap overflow")
```

And you won't get the GC overhead limit exceeded error.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually I don't understand why even if I `def` every streamed mapping inside the method I cannot get the expected behavior. I have updated my post and explained why I am messing with `def Stream`. Maybe I should have picked another approach?

Comment: Use `Iterator` instead. With `Stream`  it is tricky to tell if you are going to blow the heap or not.